# I'm looking for a sine wave audio generator for actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, generator, trigonometry

I've been searching for a sine wave generator for actionscript3. I found SION ( https://sites.google.com/site/sioncenter/ ) but it doesn't seem to accept frequency in Hz as input, it only accepts musical notes (a, b, c, etc).

I need the sine wave generator to accept frequency in Hz, so it can generate any frequency in the audible range.

Where can I find something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found exactly what I was looking for. A tutorial on how to code a simple sine wave generator in AS3 using the Sound object:

http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2669